# $\pi$ = 13, $\sqrt{2}$ = 7, $e$ =?

Tags: mathematics

[image]
<sub>From The Escape Room Advent Calendar: Puzzle book for adults</sub>

I know the answer to this puzzle.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is what it is.

Comment: Is this the latest revision of the [Indiana bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill#Approximation_of_%CF%80)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $e=11$

Indeed, looking at

> the approximate values given in the book, we can see that there are mistakes in the given number.

$\pi=13$:

> 3.141592653589*1*9… where actually $\pi$ is approximatively equal to 3.141592653589*7*9… ; the 13th digit is wrong.

$\sqrt{2}=7$:

> 1.414213*8*6… where actually $\sqrt{2}$ is approximatively equal to 1.414213*5*6… ; the 7th digit is wrong.

So:

> Since $e$ is approximatively equal to 2.718281828459…, the first wrong digit in 2.718281828419… is the 11th.